# Is there a way to get the BigQuery function or procedure name inside the function or procedure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have searched around on Google and [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) for an answer to this, and found nothing.

What I want to be able to do is something like:

```sql
DECLARE thisName string;
SET thisName = CurrentProcedure();
```

Comment: not clear yet  - please elaborate on your use case - how you then plan to use this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fetch function name, but below procedure could help you to get procedure name from call stack.

It is a bit silly but there is no way to fetch call stack without throwing and catching an exception:

```sql
-- Returns name of the procedure which calls this procedure. 
-- Returns NULL if called from top level of a script (not from a procedure).
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE yourDataset.CurrentProcedure(OUT name STRING)
BEGIN
RAISE USING MESSAGE = 'error on purpose';
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
  IF ARRAY_LENGTH(@@error.stack_trace) >= 2 THEN
    SET name = @@error.stack_trace[OFFSET(1)].location;
  END IF;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE yourDataset.yourWorkProcedure()
BEGIN
  DECLARE name STRING;
  CALL yourDataset.CurrentProcedure(name);
  SELECT name;
END;

CALL yourDataset.yourWorkProcedure();
```